# Cannot boot into GRUB menu after installing and uninstalling Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

I was using Kali Linux as a primary operating system with dual boot with windows 10 using GRUB. Unfortunately windows 10 failed and I had to reinstall it again. After re-installation, I was not able to boot into the grub menu and tried everything to find any boot settings in windows and that did no work, so I though that if I uninstalled windows that may force the bios to load from the Linux partition. That did not work and it gives me a message saying that no bootable device is found. Now, I am using a live Linux USB. So, is there any way I can restore my Kali Linux system?
Running the `fdisk -l` command gives the following output:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo fdisk -l                                               
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5993b524

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       217702400 1953521663 1735819264 827.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       217704448  238675967   20971520    10G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       238678016  349265919  110587904  52.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       349269228  350233064     963837 470.6M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       350233128 1931872807 1581639680 754.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.91 GiB, 16005464064 bytes, 31260672 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3c89495a

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         64 6867839 6867776  3.3G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2       6867840 6869311    1472  736K  1 FAT12


Disk /dev/loop0: 2.94 GiB, 3155832832 bytes, 6163736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing an OS, it overrides existing Boot Sector. Windows uses a different boot loader from Unix, and after installation, the boot sector points to Windows without any reference to Ubuntu.

Now you have 2 options :

- Use Windows boot loader & add a boot menu entry for Ubuntu. Boot into windows then use [Bootice](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2909#:%7E:text=BOOTICE%20is%20a%20boot%2Drelated,%3B%20VHD%20%2F%20VHDX%20file%20management.) to add your entry for Ubuntu.
- Use GRUB boot loader & add a boot menu entry for Windows. Mount your Windows Partition,then run `sudo os-prober` followed by `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I manged to fix the issue by reinstalling Grub, thanks